# Nginx - modify location header if it doesn't contain subpath (proxy_redirect)

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy

I have an Nginx server as a reverse proxy, ultimately what I want to achieve is that each redirect response Location header will be rewritten to add a prefix to it.
The only scenario in which I want that **the Location header URL will not be modified at all** is when the Location header URL starts with /auth.

Meaning:

Redirect response to **/any/sub/path** should be changed to **/{PREFIX_VAR}/any/sub/path**

Redirect response to **/auth/any/sub/path** should **not** be modified and remain **/auth/any/sub/path**

How can I achieve that? so it will work for relative URLs returned and full path URL? I've tried any solution out there and nothing worked

Note - the /auth URL requests are not supposed to go through my server, so it's not something I can handle in a location block.

Thanks!

Comment: Relative URLs will always point to your server. Are you trying to point the `/auth/` to somewhere else, or does the URL already contain the intended destination domain. Some more details will be useful.